# Make 5 minute data to quarter data as first row

Tags: time, group-by, sum

I would like to make 5 minute data of each row into quarter data where the first column shows the text of the first 5 minutes and the second column the sum of the first three 5-minute columns. Like this:

- 29-8-2018 00:00:00   1
- 29-8-2018 00:05:00   3
- 29-8-2018 00:10:00   5
- 29-8-2018 00:15:00   7
- 29-8-2018 00:20:00   9
- 29-8-2018 00:25:00   11

To

- 29-8-2018 00:00:00   9
- 29-8-2018 00:15:00   27

Thanks in advance, 
Allard

Comment: Please edit your question and **show your code** and  **show your database structure**. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Something like this on SQL Server:

```
select dateadd(minute, -datepart(minute, tm) % 15)), sum(val)
from T t
group by dateadd(minute, -datepart(minute, tm) % 15));
```

This does assume there are never any seconds to strip off.